# How to upgrade redis-stack-server images with latest RSCoordinator/RediSearch 2+ for cluster nodes?

Tags: redis, redis-cluster, redisearch, redis-stack-server

The redis-stack-server does include RediSearch: https://hub.docker.com/r/redis/redis-stack-server

However, the image does NOT include the latest RSCoordinator (included in RediSearch), which synchronizes indices among Redis cluster nodes. Is there any images, which upgraded the image with this functionality? Or - anyone documents/manuals on how to do it?

Also, I don't see neither module-oss.so nor module-enterprise.so in redis-stack-server lib [image].

Anyone got a tip on how to activate the syncronization of indicies with the redis-stack-server image (It's puzzling to me why the community would NOT want that functionality)?

Also, the building instructions on RediSearch README.md are simply wrong:
https://github.com/RediSearch/RediSearch/tree/master/coord

FYI: the same case was tried to solve on [GitHub for the Bitnami Image](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/21597).